# Ways to parse tuple data from variable in python

Tags: python

I am working on an API at work that pulls some connection info from our backend, and sets it as a variable.  Need some suggestions on how to parse this data to get what I need, when I need to.  Below is a sample of the output that is in my variable.

```
(ArrayOfString){
   string[] = 
      "Starting Up
- AuthCode OK
- Found 4123 Devices
Done
OK",
      "007.blahname.com AB Publishing   1.1.1.1 CentOS Linux 5.0            
",
      "027503-blah  test blah   1.1.1.2 NetScaler OS    Network Gathering   1.1.1.1 22
",
      "028072-;alskdjf; Alpha Group 192.168.19.100  CentOS Linux 5  SSH 2.2.2.2 2022
",
      "028072-4alksgjasdfserver Alpha Group 192.168.19.101  CentOS Linux 5  SSH 2.3.4.5 2022
",
```

Not sure if easily visible, but everything is tab delimited. What I need in the end, is it set up as columns, so I can search for a Device name (column 1), and read the associated IP, port, and connection method(colums 7, 8, and 6 on the 028072 example above.
Any help/ideas on where to start would be helpful.

Comment: Are you actually getting this C# (or whatever) source code to parse?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) from the standard libary.

Answer (score 0):

You can split by tabs specifically `.split('\t')` or by whitespace `.split()`, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

What you've shown us looks like C# source code. If that's what you're actually getting, you'll need to first parse the strings out of that source code, and then you can parse the columns out of those strings.

So, first:

```
r = re.compile(r'"(.*?)"', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
lines = r.findall(data)
```

Next, the first string (the one with a bunch of newlines in it) seems to be some kind of header info that you want to skip over. Also, each line has a newline in it. So, let's fix both of those: (We could have stripped that newline in the regex, but it's just as easy to do it here.)

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in lines[1:]]
```

Now, each string can be split into columns by tabs, right?

```
values = [line.split('\t') for line in lines]
```

That's it.

As an alternative, we could have done `StringIO(''.join(lines))` and passed that to `csv.reader(sio, delimiter='\t')`… and if the parsing were any more complicated than just `split`, I probably would. But in this case, I think it adds more complexity than it saves.

---

But there's a problem. If you've copied and pasted correctly, those strings do *not* have tabs in them, they have spaces. And, since the columns themselves have internal spaces, and there's no quoting or escaping, there's no unambiguous way to split them. You can write some heuristic code that tries to reconstruct the tabs by guessing at tab stops, assuming that any run of 2 or more spaces must be a tab, etc., but that's going to take a good chunk of work to do.